# jQuery: breaking out of nested $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping through rows in a list w/ `$.each`, and on each row applying a set of filters with `$.each`. I'd like to skip rows that do not match. It kinda looks like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, row) {
    count      = parseInt(row['n']);
    year       = row['year'];

    if (options.filters) {
        $.each(options.filters, function(filter, filtervalue) {
            if (row[filter] != filtervalue) return true;
        });
    }

    // Will only get here if all filters have passed
}
```

How can I get the nested `$.each` loop to skip the row if `filtervalue` does not match a given filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to skip a row if there is not at least one filter that `filtervalue` does not match, right? Then don't skip a row **iff** the `filtervalue` matches at least one filter.

```
$.each(data, function(i, row) {
    count      = parseInt(row['n']);
    year       = row['year'];


    // if there are no filters, don't skip the row (right? ;-)
    var skipRow = !!options.filters;

    if (options.filters) {
        $.each(options.filters, function(filter, filtervalue) {
            if (row[filter] == filtervalue) {
                skipRow = false;
            }
        });
    }

    if (skipRow) return true;
}
```